# Python list comprehension only works in specific order

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a small lines of code (loc) counter;
It's pretty straightforward, so I thought I'd give it a shot
as a pretty list comprehension.

However, when executing the code; something strange happens :
When I execute the code like so

```
from os import listdir, path

PYTHON_FILES = [
    filename for filename in listdir(path.dirname(__file__))
    if filename.endswith('.py')
]

def count_lines(list_of_files):
    """Count sloc in iterable list_of_files"""

    loc = 0

    # Redundant, but code only works
    # when this part is in
    # Even though what it does gets overwritten
    for file in list_of_files:
        for line in open(file):
            if not line.strip().startswith('#'):
                if not line.strip().startswith('"'):
                    if not line.isspace():
                        loc += 1

    loc = len([
        line for line in open(file)
        for file in list_of_files
        if not line.strip().startswith('#')
        and not line.strip().startswith('"')
        and not line.isspace()
    ])

    print(loc)

count_lines(PYTHON_FILES)
```

It runs smoothly and outputs as expected. 
But when I replace `count_lines` with this :

```
def count_lines(list_of_files):
    """Count sloc in iterable list_of_files"""

    loc = len([
        line for line in open(file)
        for file in list_of_files
        if not line.strip().startswith('#')
        and not line.strip().startswith('"')
        and not line.isspace()
    ])

    print(loc)
```

I get :

```
  File "counter.py", line 22, in count_lines
    line for line in open(file)
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why this is happening :
The `file` in the for loop should be local to that iteration.
So why is it impacting everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## List comprehension

That is the expected behavior. List comprehension has at the right side a sequence of loops (`for <var> in <iterable>`) and filters (`if <expr>`). It can only use variables that are defined outside the list comprehension, or the ones that are defined in the previous loop.

So you can not write `for x in y for y in z`, since `y` is not yet defined in the first sequence. You need to perform a **stratification** yourself such that variables you use are defined before the loop statement.

This is logical, since if you write:

```
[
    line for line in open(file)
    for file in list_of_files
    if not line.strip().startswith('#')
    and not line.strip().startswith('"')
    and not line.isspace()
]
```

it is equivalent to the following procedural code:

```
result = []
for line in open(file):
    for file in list_of_files:
        if not line.strip().startswith('#') and not line.strip().startswith('"') and not line.isspace():
            result.append(line)
```

So here you would have an outer loop that iterates over a variable that is assigned in an inner loop. That makes no sense. Although there is definitely a way to do the ordering (stratification) automatically, it has advantages to do it yourself since the order of the inner/outer loop also determines the order of the results.

## "Leaking variables"

Why don't you get an error in your first approach? Since you first use `for` loops, the variables leak. Indeed if we write:

```
>>> for x in [1,4,2,5]:
...     pass
... 
>>> x
5
```

we see that **after the `for` loop**, the variable **`x` still exists**, and has the last assigned value. So if you later write list comprehension, it will first evaluate the first `for` loop in the list comprehension, which is `for line in open(file)`. `file` is still assigned, so the last file is opened and processed.

Note that `line` will only take lines from the last file, and we will process each line in the last file many times (for every `file in files`). But we will not process another file than the last one (but the numbers will be multiplied by the number of files).

Comment: But then why does it work properly when I leave the loop before the comprehension? Whatever the loop produces is overwritten.

Comment: @C._: because in your first case, the names are also assigned by `for` loops. In Python-2.x the names in `for` loops "leak". So after the `for` loop, there is a variable named `file`. In the answer I write that outer variables are also acceptable, but it does not makes any sense.

Comment: Maybe, but this is python 3. I follow your logic as to what comprehensions do on their own, but why does it work here (in 3.x)?

Comment: @C._: well in Python-3.x variable names in `for` loops also leak, only for loops in list comprehension do no longer leak.

Comment: @C._: I added an additional section to explain the behavior.

Comment: I see. Any reason why this is so? Anyways, thanks for you time!

Comment: @C._: well Python sees every variable that is assigned in a scope as a local variable that exists in the entire scope (before and after assignment). The main difference between Python-2 and Python-3 is that in Python-3.x, list comprehension has its own scope.